# Evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate the following integral:
>   $$\displaystyle \int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{a}}}$$
>   Where $a$ is an arbitrary constant.

How do I solve this?

**EDIT:** I would appreciate it if you do consider the case when $a<0$, but this is an integral that I encountered in a physics problem. Considering $a>0$ will suffice.

---

I tried the substitution $$x=a\cos \theta$$

And I ended up with:

$$\displaystyle a^{3/2}\int\dfrac{\sqrt {\cos\theta}.\sin\theta.d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}}$$

How do I simplify this further?

Comment: Hint:  $a>0$  $$\dfrac1x=\dfrac{\sec^2y}a$$  and for $0>a=-b$ $$\dfrac1x=\dfrac{\tan^2y}b$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your substitution seems to make the problem more complicated, since the square root terms still remain.

Instead, we first simply $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{a}}}$ by writing the two fractions on the denominator as a single fraction, and then flipping the fraction, to obtain $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt {ax}}{\sqrt {a-x}}$ (assuming $a>0$). From here, making the substitution $x=a \sin^2 \theta$ yields $$\int \frac{a \sin \theta}{\sqrt a \cos \theta} 2a \sin \theta \cos \theta d\theta = \int 2a^{\frac{3}{2}} \sin^2 \theta d \theta$$
which can now be easily solved.

For $a<0$, simply let $b=-a$. We will obtain $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt b}{\sqrt {b+x}}$ in the integrand, from which the substitution $x=b \tan^2 \theta$ will work.

Comment: What happen if $a<0?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee If a is negative, we can replace the subtraction with addition and let $b=-a$, and now use $x=b \tan^2 \theta$.

Comment: The assumption should find a place in the post

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks, I’ll add it in now.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\frac1t$ and $b =\frac1a$

\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}}
=& -\int \frac{dt}{t^2\sqrt{t-b}}
=-\int \frac{1}{b\sqrt{t-b}}d\left(\frac{t-b}t\right)\\
\overset{ibp}=&-\frac{\sqrt{t-b}}{bt}+\frac1{b}\int \frac{d(\sqrt{t-b})}{(t-b)+b}\\
=&\ \begin{cases}
-\frac{\sqrt{t-b}}{bt}+\frac{1}{b^{3/2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{t-b}{\sqrt b} & b>0\\
-\frac{\sqrt{t-b}}{bt}-\frac{1}{2(-b)^{3/2}}\ln\frac{\sqrt{t-b}-\sqrt{-b}}{\sqrt{t-b}+\sqrt{-b}}& b<0\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It can be rewritten (for $0<x<a$) as
$$ \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}} = \int \frac{\sqrt{ax}dx}{\sqrt{a-x}}$$
We can use substitution $x = a\sin^2\theta$, $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get
$$ \int \frac{\sqrt{ax}dx}{\sqrt{a-x}} = 2a^\frac32 \int \frac{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta}\sin\theta\cos\theta \,d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}} = 2a^\frac32\int \sin^2\theta\, d\theta$$
For $x<a<0$ we use subsstitution $x=a\cosh^2t$, $t>0$ and we get
$$ \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}} = \int \frac{\sqrt{(-a)(-x)}dx}{\sqrt{(-x)-(-a)}} = -2(-a)^\frac32\int \cosh^2t\, dt$$
Finally, for $a<0<x$ we use $x=-a\sinh^2t$, $t>0$ to get
$$ \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}} = \int \frac{\sqrt{(-a)x}dx}{\sqrt{x+(-a)}} = 2(-a)^\frac32\int \sinh^2 t\, dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Letting $b=\frac1a$ and $y^2=\frac{1}{x}-b$, then $$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}}& =-2 \int \frac{d y}{\left(y^2+b\right)^2} \\
& =\int \frac{1}{y} d\left(\frac{1}{y^2+b}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{y\left(y^2+b\right)}+\int \frac{1}{y^2\left(y^2+b\right)} d y \\
& =\frac{1}{y\left(y^2+b\right)}+\frac{1}{b} \int\left(\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{y^2+b}\right) d y \\
& =-\frac{y}{b\left(y^2+b\right)}+\frac{1}{b} \int \frac{1}{y^2+b} d y
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can conclude that
$$
I=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-a x \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}+a^{\frac{3}{2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}-1}\right) \text { if } a>0 \\
-a x \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}+(-b)^{\frac{3}{2}} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}+\sqrt{-\frac{1}{a}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}-\sqrt{-\frac{1}{a}}}\right| \text { if } a<0
\end{array}\right.
$$